# Android deep linking dynamic suffix

Tags: android, android-manifest, deep-linking

I would like to open my app from link but it doesn't work. I have link: https://www.example.com/stream/0QsmCsh8wJng

If I remove android:pathPattern="/stream" then it works. But I need the pathPattern.

In manifest I have this:

```
<activity
      android:name=".activities.StreamActivity"
      android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
      android:parentActivityName=".activities.DashboardActivity"
      android:screenOrientation="sensor"
      android:theme="@style/AppThemeFullScreen"
      android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize">
      <meta-data
           android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
           android:value=".activities.DashboardActivity"/>

           <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
                <data android:scheme="https" android:host="www.example.com" android:pathPattern="/stream" />
            </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe `pathPattern` needs to be a *complete* URL ([source](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element.html)), so you might need something like `android:pathPattern="/stream/.*"`

However, using `android:pathPrefix="/stream"` would be simpler, and seems like it should take care of what you're trying to do.